# Importing a component from another component

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I'm trying to call a child component's function from a parent component.

As I understand, the best way to go about this is to use ViewChild.

I understand the logic of it all, but for some reason I can't import the child component into the parent component, it gives me the error:

**Cannot find module '../claim-header/claim-header.component'.**

This is the import section in my parent component: (Claim)

`import { ClaimHeaderComponent } from '../claim-header/claim-header.component';`

I've tried them all:

```
import { ClaimHeaderComponent } from './claim-header';
import { ClaimHeaderComponent } from './claim-header/claim-header';
import { ClaimHeaderComponent } from '../claim-header';
import { ClaimHeaderComponent } from '../../components/claim-header-component';
```

etc.

For reference, the rest of the imports work fine as long as they're not components:

```
import { ClaimDetail } from '../../modules/models/claim';
import { ClaimsService } from '../../modules/services/claims.service';
```

This is the declaration of my child component:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'fhp-claim-header',
    templateUrl: 'claim-header.component.html'
})

export class ClaimHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
   ...
}
```

And my folder layout:

[Folder layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyIOd.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using

```
../claim-header/claim-header.component
```

Explanation.

./ refers to the root folder of the underlying folder -> **Components** folder

[image]

My folder structure for your demo

[image]

Comment: `./` doesn't refer to root directory. It refers to current directory in relative path. Only `/` refers to root directory of the project structure.